# Sql query to fetch a value from multiple rows based on a indicators

Tags: mysql

I would need an sql query to fetch rows for the following scenario

```
Cust Id.            Ind
1.                   U
1.                   U
1.                   N
2.                   U
2.                   U
```

I want to fetch the rows where the cust Id has all the multiple rows with value 'U' only. I do not want to fetch the rows where the cust Id have value for ind other than 'U'

In this case the output should be

```
2.       U
2.       U
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da98e/1

```
SELECT CustId FROM my_table
GROUP BY CustId
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(Ind ='U')
```

Comment: decent solution.. however having re-evaluates the table which may be slower than my answer. thoughts?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Probably. To me it seems very close. The performance could be different but I am not sure which one wins. I like your solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/587d7/1)

What you want to do is self join (left join so we can have nulls) the table where its anything but 'U' and make sure it is null.. Meaning we have a customer with only 'U' ind. This is called an exclusive join

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.custid
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table tt ON tt.CustId = t.CustId AND tt.Ind <> 'U'
WHERE tt.CustId IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table_name where  
          CustId NOT IN (select CustId from table_name where Ind <>'U')
AND CustId='U'
```

This will work